similar output from st_as_sf() and fortify()
I'm trying to get the same output with sf::st_as_sf() that I get with the soon-to-be-deprecated ggplot2::fortify():
library(rworldmap)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

world_map <- rworldmap::getMap()

points <- ggplot2::fortify(world_map)

points_2 <- sf::st_as_sf(world_map) 

returns a df with columns "long", "lat", "order", "hole", "piece", "id", and "group", where multiple polygons for a country (=id) and their respective lat-long are a unique row (=group).
      long      lat order  hole piece          id         group
1 61.21082 35.65007     1 FALSE     1 Afghanistan Afghanistan.1
2 62.23065 35.27066     2 FALSE     1 Afghanistan Afghanistan.1
3 62.98466 35.40404     3 FALSE     1 Afghanistan Afghanistan.1
4 63.19354 35.85717     4 FALSE     1 Afghanistan Afghanistan.1

st_as_sf appears to keep the additional polygons in the list-column "geometry". Is there an option for st_as_sf to return the dataframe with the list flattened in the same way fortify does?

Do you need it for platting or for something else? ggplot2 supports sf objects (frames with geometry column)  through  geom_sf().

I'm doing some manipulation of the dataframe before plotting.

Can you give some examples of those manipulations? Currently I'm having bit hard time coming up with a case where I'd prefer fortified frame over sf object and methods from sf or other packages that target sf objects. If moving your current code base to sf is not an option, it's understandable.

fortify is a generic function. The specific method is ggplot2:::fortify.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame which in turn calls other fortify methods for the various components of the map.
You can create your own little function that does much the same thing:
my_fortify <- function(map) {
  do.call("rbind",
    lapply(map@polygons, function(x) {
      do.call("rbind",
        lapply(seq_along(x@Polygons), function(i) {
        df <- setNames(as.data.frame(x@Polygons[[i]]@coords), c("long", "lat"))
        df$order <- 1:nrow(df)
        df$hole <- x@Polygons[[i]]@hole
        df$piece <- i
        df$id <- x@ID
        df$group <- paste(x@ID, i, sep = '.')
        df
        }))
    })
  )
}

So now we have:
head(my_fortify(world_map))
#>       long      lat order  hole piece          id         group
#> 1 61.21082 35.65007     1 FALSE     1 Afghanistan Afghanistan.1
#> 2 62.23065 35.27066     2 FALSE     1 Afghanistan Afghanistan.1
#> 3 62.98466 35.40404     3 FALSE     1 Afghanistan Afghanistan.1
#> 4 63.19354 35.85717     4 FALSE     1 Afghanistan Afghanistan.1
#> 5 63.98290 36.00796     5 FALSE     1 Afghanistan Afghanistan.1
#> 6 64.54648 36.31207     6 FALSE     1 Afghanistan Afghanistan.1

and
ggplot(my_fortify(world_map), aes(long, lat, group = group)) + geom_polygon()



This is perfect, with added bonus that I no longer require sf as a dependency in the package.  Thanks so much.
